# Making custom toggle buttons in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is there any way to make a custom toggle button in Access? I'm looking to create an on/off switch. The built in toggle button is fugly.

I have already created the on/off/hover images in photoshop. Is there a way to import them code them to work like the built in toggle button?

Comment: In MS Access 2010, you can certainly add an image to a toggle button, you will need a .bmp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be easy enough to simply adjust the picture property, for example:

```
Private Sub Toggle0_Click()
    If Me.Toggle0 Then
        Me.Toggle0.Picture = "Z:\Docs\Picture1.bmp"
    Else
        Me.Toggle0.Picture = "Z:\Docs\Picture2.bmp"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Access 2010 has an AMAZING button editor, and the combinations and glow and shadow effects are amazing. In less time to type this sentence, I made these toggle buttons:

[image]

In above the button differences is when the button is depressed or not (so dark blue examples above are those that are depressed)

Here is a screen cap of the built in tools in Access used to create the above – I did not use any 3rd party tools to build the above. As pointed out by others here you can include an image with the button.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just one possible way (I'm sure there are many):-

Put both your images into image controls on the form, and line them up on top of each other.
In the click event of each control, use something like this:-

```
Private Sub img1_Click()
Me.img2.Visible = True
Me.img1.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub img2_Click()
Me.img1.Visible = True
Me.img2.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Where img1 and img2 are your "on" and "off" image controls. You can set one of them visible in the load event of your form, and you can tell what the status of your "switch" is, by inspecting the visible property of the controls.